# What is the reason for high frequency noise when amplifier is powered with battery?

Tags: amplifier, battery-charging, noise, battery-operated, sound

Hi I made a small headphone amp and powered it using lipo battery.voltage is stepped up to 5v.everything is working with direct supply (ie., while charging battery)but as soon as I unplug the charger ,I am getting high frequency output to amplifier.what could be the reason?
Note:this is happening even when battery is fully charged and there is absolutely no noise when battery is charging.

Comment: Hello, could you be a bit more specific? If you can create or share a schematic that will be helpful. What is the high frequency? 1kHz, 1GHz? Which amplifier?

Comment: Its a mini  tda1308 board.I don't have a scope to measure the frequency but its audible through headphones.as I mentioned this noise disappears while battery is charging.

Comment: Looks like something starts oscillating when you remove the charger. With no scope that is difficult to solve but at a guess I would start with adding a capacitor over the supply pins.

Comment: Should I add capacitor after step up for filtering?

Comment: I schematic would be better but my reasoning is as follows: The charger has a probably a bulk capacitor at its output. This is the component closest to your circuit and thus removing the charger it has a great impact on the functioning of your circuit. Bridging the charge pins with a capacitor of your own is simple and can be done without soldering. If the frequency goes away you have a solution. If not, try to borrow a scope.

Comment: Also, the [choice of capacitor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/152180/why-does-my-circuit-work-with-ceramic-capacitors-but-not-electrolytic) can be important. Try an electrolytic and if that doesn't help, add a polyester or ceramic cap.